# Google Sheet range of all cells filled in

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am creating a custom query that combines data on multiple sheets to query against. Is there a way to get all of the cells that have values? Right now I have to go into each sheet and determine the last row of cells and specifically declare the range.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: do you specifically want to use a Formula with queries or are you open to use Apps Script?